# Disable (grey out) the parent Category and make it not selectable

Tags: html, html-select

I have a multiselect and i want to disable the parent category from being transferred and i am struggling with it for a long time .

Please see image , i want to disable the ones in yellow with whatever code (i am using wordpres )
[image]

I Got it working somehow and not selectable when the windows loads but when subcategory is selected , all of them enabled again , any help with the code that they stay not selectable 
The Code is :

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload =function () {
var fastInternet = document.getElementById("countrylist");
for (var i = 0; i < fastInternet.options.length; i++) {
    var value = fastInternet.options[i].value;
   if(value == '47' || value == '52'  || value == '57'   || value == '61' )  {
        //need to hide this
        fastInternet.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

    }

    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: PLEASE don't paste this much code! Post only the relevant sections... and try to format it, as no one will read these two lines or even try to format them for you. For example, remove all but two or three options in your code. Together with a proper formatting, it will be much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Without reading your code, here are two alternatives making an `<option>` unselectable.

1. Use an `<optgroup>`

   ```
   <select>
     <optgroup label="Category 1">
       <option>Option 1</option>
       <option>Option 2</option>
     </optgroup>    
     <optgroup label="Category 2">
       <option>Option 3</option>
       <option>Option 4</option>
     </optgroup>
   </select>
   ```

   [Documentation @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)
2. In case you can't use the `<optgroup>`-tag, then simply disable the options which are not supposed to be selectable:

   ```
   <option disabled>an option</option>
   ```

---

You clarified that you need to use JS and I'm going to assume that jQuery is available:

```
$("#myselect option").each(function(el) {
    if($(this).text().slice(0, 2) != "--") {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }
});

$("#myselect option:not([disabled])").first().attr("selected", "selected");
```

The logic behind is, that we check each `<option>` if it's inner text does not begin with `--`. If this is true, then it's a category (according to your screenshot) and we disable this option.
Last thing to keep in mind is, that we need to select a non-disabled option afterwards, otherwise a category is selected automatically when the site loads.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcW5E/).

Comment: Thanks Basti but the country list is generated by a php script on the site and need something in javascript to disable those options ,

Comment: Thanks Basti for the help !

Comment: @user3186589 is jQuery available or do you need pure JS? Besides, this is valuable information, that you need this in javascript. You should've added this to the question.

Comment: @user3186589 see my edit for an implementation in jQuery. Also, please don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Basti , i cant't make this work , Jquery is Available , can i send you somewhere some test login to add a listing and look at the page source ? i will gladly pay you for that .

Comment: @user3186589 No. But i added a fiddle to show that it works, see my edited answer above. Sure, you'll have to replace `myselect` with whatever your selects id is.

Comment: As long as it is a `select` tag this code will be fine. If your `<select>` doesn't have an id, then either give it one or change both jquery-selectors.

Comment: Sorry . but what is the jquery-selectors ?

Comment: Google "jquery selectors", first result is [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I will Give it a try again , if not successful i will give it up thanks alot anyway for your help Basti , Vielen DANK !

Comment: Anyone can improve the above code to make them stay not selectable ?